# Cannot add item to Sitecore cache

Tags: caching

I am trying to create a new Sitecore 9.0.1 XP cache and add an item to it. I can create the cache just fine. When I call the Add method it executes just fine but nothing is added to the cache.

I have a local variable call viewCache

`private readonly ICache<string> viewCache;`

I have tried to do both of this.

```
   this.viewCache = Sitecore.Caching.CacheManager.GetNamedInstance<string>(
       "viewCache",
       10,
       true);

    // Also tried this instead of the above line. NOT both at the same time
   this.viewCache = new Cache("viewCache", 10);
```

Both execute just fine and create a cache object.

Later on I make this call.

`this.viewCache.Add(cacheKey, returnViewpath);`

Again it executes just fine. However, when I look at the cache the count is always 0 and I can't get the value out of the cache as it says it is null.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you just need `ICache` not `ICache<string>`

Also, Make sure your memory size is right. You want to use the string sizer, not an int. So, like `StringUtil.ParseSizeString("10MB")`

Here's an example of some heavily redacted code. Idea here is this shows you how I setup a Cache Service that could be exposed by dependency injection:

```
public class SampleCacheService : ISampleCacheService
{
    private readonly SampleCacheSettings _cacheSettings;
    private readonly ICache _SampleCache;

    public SampleCacheService(SampleCacheSettings cacheSettings)
    {
        _cacheSettings = cacheSettings;
        _SampleCache = CacheManager.GetNamedInstance(_cacheSettings.Name, StringUtil.ParseSizeString(_cacheSettings.MaxSize), true);
    }

    public SampleCacheSettings Settings => _cacheSettings;

    public void Clear()
    {
        _SampleCache.Clear();
    }

    public void Refresh()
    {
        try
        {
            Refresh(_cacheSettings.SettingsItem().PhysicianRoot.Target.Path);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error($"[Sample Cache Error] Message: {ex.Message}", this);
            Log.Error($"[Sample Cache Error] Stack: {ex.StackTrace}", this);
        }
    }

    public void Refresh(string contentPath)
    {
        Refresh(null, contentPath);
    }

    public void Refresh(Item[] itemArray, string contentPath = "")
    {
        //Fetch API
        var Sample = _someApiService.GetAsync(npiList);

        if (Sample == null) return;

        //Iterate List Add To Cache
        foreach (var sample in Sample.data.entities)
        {
            if (Contains(sample.id))
                _SampleCache.Remove(sample.id);

            Add(sample.id, sample);
        }
    }

    public bool Contains(string key)
    {
        return _SampleCache.ContainsKey(key);
    }

    public Entity Get(string key)
    {
        if (!Contains(key))
            Add(key);

        return (Entity)_SampleCache.GetValue(key);
    }



    private void Add(string key)
    {
        var Sample = _someApiService.GetAsync(new List<string>(){key});

        if (Sample?.data?.entities == null || !Sample.data.entities.Any()) return;

        if (Contains(key))
            _SampleCache.Remove(key);

        _SampleCache.Add(key, Sample.data.entities.FirstOrDefault());

    }
    private void Add(string key, Entity rating)
    {
        _SampleCache.Add(key, rating);
    }

}
```

Comment: Right. I only listed both calls to show that I have tried it both ways, not both at the same time though.

Comment: I think you just need `ICache` not `ICache<string>`

Comment: Also, Make sure your memory size is right. You want to use the string sizer, not an int. So, like `StringUtil.ParseSizeString("10MB")`

Comment: Yep, that was it. Needed to use `StringUtil.ParseSizeString("10MB")` and that fixed it. I kept ICahce<string> and it still works so it seems the key is setting the cache size as you noted and not with an int. Thanks!